# Expose JavaScript Module's Function to Entire HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6, inline-scripting

Consider this basic function in `/js/foo.mjs`:

```js
export function foo( ) {
    console.log('Hello, Modularity!');
};
```

How to import `foo` function inside an HTML document, so it can be used inline?

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=module src=/js/foo.mjs></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick=foo()>Modules are Cool</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes, I just can define the function in `window` object:

```js
window['foo'] = function _foo( ) {
    console.log('Hello, Whatever!');
};
```

But this is something I want to avoid; maybe there is a way to somehow import a function or a variable so it will be accessible inside the whole HTML document?

I guess I can do this:

```js
onclick='import { foo } from "/js/foo.mjs"; foo()'
```

But this is ugly as hell.

Comment: Inline event handlers are "ugly as hell" too in my opinion... Why not use `addEventListener`?

Comment: This making no sense, it's like saying "I want global variables but don't want global variables"

Comment: @DanStarns man, I have bipolar disorder.